# Modify the name of all files a type in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a folder that have many files named like this:

```
4474_uff_E=443.36_out.pdbqt
AQbtc_uff_E=443.36_uff_E=396.28_uff_E=391.20_out.pdbqt
5770_uff_E=859.40_out.pdbqt
5770_uff_E=859.40_uff_E=859.31_out.pdbqt
Nice_uff_E=379.35_uff_E=367.83_uff_E=367.27_uff_E=367.26_out.pdbqt
Weird_and_funny_compound_uff_E=300.77_uff_E=299.90_out.pdbqt
```

I am trying to remove the part of the file name that start with `uff` and keep the `out.pdbqt` part. So basically from `AQbtc_uff_E=443.36_uff_E=396.28_uff_E=391.20_out.pdbqt` to `AQbtc_out.pdbqt`.

I have a similar script that add `_out` to the file name

```
import sys
import glob
import re
import os
from os.path import dirname
files = glob.glob('**/*.pdbqt', recursive = True)
for file in files:
    name = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    os.rename(name+".pdbqt", name+"_out.pdbqt")
```

But having trouble on how to modify that.

Appreciate any input!

Answer (score 0):

Use the string `.find()` function to locate the start of the substring "uff_" within the filename.

```
filename = 'AQbtc_uff_E=443.36_uff_E=396.28_uff_E=391.20_out.pdbqt'
x = filename.find('uff_') # returns 6
```

Then make a new filename, discarding everything from the original filename after that location, and appending "out.pdbqt" to the end:

```
new_filename = filename[:x] + 'out.pdbqt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input.

The working script I have came up based on that is:

```
import sys
import glob
import re
import os
from os.path import dirname
files = glob.glob('**/*.pdbqt', recursive = True)
for file in files:
    x = file.find('uff_')
    if x != -1: 
        new = file[:x] + 'out.pdbqt'
        print(new)
        os.rename(file, new)
```